# IE8 beforeBlur() and postBlur() events

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, blur

i have a function in javascript.

```
    onBlur: function(comp) {
    if (this.leftTextField.hasFocus || this.rightTextField.hasFocus) return;
    this.beforeBlur();
    this.hasFocus = false;
    .......
    ........

    this.fireEvent('blur');
    this.postBlur();
},
```

In firefox it works as following. When `this.fireEvent('blur')` is fired `this.postBlur();` is completed and next `this.fireEvent('blur')`  is completed.
In IE8 when `this.fireEvent('blur')` and `this.postBlur();` is completed the next line completed is `if (this.leftTextField.hasFocus || this.rightTextField.hasFocus) return;` and because of that code does not work as espected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: To avoid all such kind of browser compatibility use jQuery. It will take care of browser compatibility. When you are dealing with IE you will have to take extra care .

Comment: I can`t use jQuery for my project. I`m using extJs framework, for my javascript.